# Angular Dynamically load select options based on selected tab

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

The following code populates a select based on the tab you have selected.  My question is how can i do this by loading the select options via api or just an external source?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/H0D9S8SK6HLDVlxM1RQm)

Comment: Well you can use the `$http` service in angular to get some JSON - is that you're referring to?

Comment: I was more asking exactly how, not just the mechanism ($http | restangular | ...)

Comment: The purpose was to see if you were aware of the mechanism and how to use it - if you were already familiar then there was no need to explain it (sometimes the asker is already aware of a given technique but it won't work in their situation, etc.).  Do you need an actual $http example of what you're trying to accomplish, or do the other answers you received suffice?

Comment: I was looking for an example, of a good way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Populating selects from an external api is no different. When the controller inits, have it run out and get the options (or better yet, resolve them before he controller is initialized) and bind that scope variable to the select. I.e.

In the controller:

```
module.controller...function(scope, service) {

  scope.selectOptions = [];

  service.get().then(function(response){
    scope.selectOptions = response.data;
  });

}
```

In the view:

```
<select ng-model="selectedDocument" ng-options="option.name for option in selectOptions"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out AngularJS's documentation for the $http service 
http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs/api/ng.$http.

With it, you can call an internal (or external) web service that can respond to your input (input being the selected tab id) with the appropriate JSON response.

In your JavaScript you can load these values upfront, or on-demand when clicking on the appropriate tab.